# Исправление некорректной кодировки

Tags: apache, кодировка, веб-программирование, utf-8

Загрузил сайт на хостинг, и вместо текста вижу «�����». Хотя на `localhost` все было нормально. Подскажите, как исправить данную ошибку? Переводить каждый файл в `UTF-8`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте в файле `.htaccess` добавить такую строчку:

```
AddDefaultCharset cp1251
```

Но, конечно, лучше было сразу в Юникоде делать, а лучше перекодировать, а в локалхостовский `.htaccess` добавить

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

Comment: Пробовал, не работает =(

Comment: Ладно, пошел я менять формат, Спасибо =)

Answer (score 1):

Смотря как заливался дамп, из какой кодировки в какую.

Изменить можно, опять таки в htaccess.

Вообще хорошо бы уже давно все файлы в UTF8 перевести да и БД тоже!

Comment: Просто, если перевожу в UTF-8 то на локалхосте проблемы с кодировкой

Comment: Значит win1251.

Изначально нужно делать так чтобы было хорошо, а не думать потом что вс1 плохо и нужно все-все переписывать!

Comment: Так, что мне делать, просто много файликов переводить :)

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251">
```

Просто прописать этот тег в `<head></head>`

Попробуй другие кодировки прописать:

- windows-1250
- windows-1252
- utf-8

Comment: Знаю такое дело, но не помогает

Comment: А сайтик можно?

Comment: Вот pokess.ru

Comment: <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
стоит перед Doctype. В этом и проблема)
Его тоже в head надо

Comment: И еще у тебя
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; CONTENT="text/html; Charset=Windows-1251" />

А надо
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1251" />

Comment: Также, ничего не изменилось :)

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html> попробуй вместо своего doctype/

Comment: Также =))))